# How to check the form that is changing the value in the table?

Tags: forms, field, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a **Form** on *Design's Form* I have a StringEdit.
This *StringEdit* represents a field on *myTable*.

I want to create in *MyTable* in *modifiedField* method a my rule:

when I modified this StringEdit copy this value on another Field in the same Table.

I used this code :

```
case fieldNum (MyTable, MyFiledSringEdit) :
if (caller.args().name() == formStr (myFormName) )
this.myFieldToChange= this.MyFiledSringEdit;
break;
```

Without `if (caller.args().name() == formStr (myFormName) )`  work well, but
I want to check if I changed the StringEdit (and then modified *myFiledSringEdit*).

If I changed the value form *myFormName* I do this rule else nothing to do.

I heve to create a method looklike : *initFrommyFormName* ? 
Or how should I do who is editing the field ?

**I want to find form who changed value in a table .**

** I know it is not correct to use that if condition

** *myFiledSringEdit* - DataSource : MyTable ; DataField : MyFiledSringEdit

thansk all!!

enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the update in the `formFormName` form, then do the change in the modified method of the forms datasource field or on the control itself if not bound to a field.

Do not attempt parameter sniffing in the `modifiedField` method of the table.